# making an IVR with android, possible?

Tags: android

is it possible to detect the number key that the one at the other end of a call has pressed?!!! I mean just like what happens during an [IVR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_voice_response)

Comment: possible duplicate of [DTMF detection on receiving an incoming call on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889779/dtmf-detection-on-receiving-an-incoming-call-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys in a telephone system emit a combined sound known as [DTMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) ie two pure sinus-signals, the combination of the two frequencies identify the key that was pressed.

There is Java code to decode and generate DTMF codes, find one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534721/is-there-any-libraryjar-file-for-dtmf-decoding-in-android) and another one [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-dtmf/).  This code is typically implemented as a [Goertzel filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm).